# Heremaps display is intermittent

Tags: here-api

We integrated HERE map with free account. HERE map display works as expected but sometimes display does not work and the issue is intermittent. We did not find any JS issue in browser console. Our site is enabled is HTTPS and in HERE map coding, we set isSecure to true

Any one experienced HERE map intermittent display issue.?

Answer (score 0):

Map display works without any specific known issues.

Most probably a connectivity issue on your side ; open the browser console and see if tiles are loading correctly. See screenshot below.

Try also on another wifi/LAN, home...

[image: screenshot]